# how to quit sshuttle and get system networking back to normal in VBox

Tags: virtualbox, ssh

I love sshuttle.  My new fav toy.  But...when i run from the command line and I use ctl-c to quit....my networking is screwed and I have to restart the VM.  Using 12.04

Here is how i start from the command line to divert all traffic to a ec2 isntances using a ssh config file.

```
 ubuntu@ubuntu:~$  sshuttle  -r ec2-fff-fff-fff-fff.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 0/0

./ssh/config
Host *compute.amazonaws.com
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    User ubuntu
    IdentityFile  /home/ubuntu/.ec2/aws_development_oregon.pem
```

now...in the terminal...I use ctrl-c to kill the tunnel.  But...how to a failsafe reset from the command line without having to restart the VBox?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Find the PID of sshuttle using the `pgrep` command:

```
pgrep sshuttle
```

and terminate it using the `kill` command:

```
kill -15 <PID>
```

If you have only one instance of sshuttle running and no other program containing `sshuttle` in its name, you can use:

```
pkill -15 sshuttle
```

To terminate the process.

Restart the `networking` service specific to you Linux distribution (`sudo systemctl restart networking` on Ubuntu).

Please note that a saner way of dealing with starting/stopping/restarting daemons would be to [create a service file](https://perfecto25.medium.com/using-sshuttle-as-a-service-bec2684a65fe) (link specific to sshuttle).